# Exact amount of line in Windows Phone textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to somehow get the exact amount of lines in a Windows Phone (8) textbox. I have been searching around but could not really find the answer for this. And I cannot just take the text as a string and split on the newline character. Dis is very unrealiable for the type of text that my textbox has. Do you have any idea how this can be done?

EDIT:
Just to clarify, I need to know the amount of physically displayed lines sothat I know when the textbox is full sothat I can start removing lines at the top, moving all other lines up and then adding new lines at the bottom to get a sort of scrolling effect. This means that stuff like textwrapping can cause new line.

Comment: " And I cannot just take the text as a string and split on the newline character. Dis is very unrealiable for the type of text that my textbox has" - so what determines  a newline?

Comment: Text wrapping and some other unknown character

Comment: Text wrapping is not a newline...

Comment: For my purpose it as I want to determine when the textbox has reached the maximum amount of physically displayed lines sothat I can get it to start removing lines at the top for each one added to the bottom.

Comment: If you know the height of one line and you're using a fixed font size, then divide that by the `ActualHeight` of the `TextBlock` to determine the number of lines?

Comment: Why are you using a TextBox?  Perhaps a readonly control like textblock is more appropriate.  Is the text being added by the user or is it filled with code or binding?  If the user is typing the text, does your code delete what they've already typed.

Comment: Not this is filled with code and a textblock would work but I still have to figure out the line count.

Comment: The part I'm not understanding is you say you want sort of a scrolling effect....why not just enable the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and just get your scrolling effect without re-inventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone Textbox control is limited by its height property, not by number of lines. The number of lines can be determined by filling the textbox with text manually and then counting.

The maximum number of lines in a textbox will ultimately be determined by the font family and font size you are using.